# Google Test : looking for a working example for passing additional arguments to invoked function

Tags: googletest

I am following the example in [gMock Cookbook](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#FunctionsAsActions). I have issues compiling it. If you have a working example for passing additional arguments to invoked function, I'll be grateful if you could share a link.

I placed all the code under "..." in "TEST_F(FooTest, Test)" declaration. I placed the rest of the code in *.h file, adding a class Foo with two virtual functions according to the code in MockFoo. I added a class FooTest that ingerits from testing::Test. I added include statements to gtest.h and gmock.h.

I use g++ 9.3.0 to build my code.

 Build results in the following compiler errors.

```
In file included from /home/gidi/temp/gtest/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:145,
                 from /home/gidi/temp/gtest/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:57,
                 from Test.h:2,
                 from Test.cpp:1:
Test.h:14:20: error: ‘testing::internal::Function<int(int, int)>::Result MockFoo::Sum(testing::internal::ElemFromList<0, int, int>::type, testing::internal::ElemFromList<1, int, int>::type)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
   14 |   MOCK_METHOD(int, Sum, (int x, int y), (override));
      |                    ^~~
/home/gidi/temp/gtest/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-pp.h:17:31: note: in definition of macro ‘GMOCK_PP_IDENTITY’
   17 | #define GMOCK_PP_IDENTITY(_1) _1
      |                               ^~
/home/gidi/temp/gtest/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h:93:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_IMPL’
   93 |   GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_IMPL(                                            \
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/gidi/temp/gtest/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-pp.h:152:39: note: in expansion of macro ‘GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_ARG_4’
  152 | #define GMOCK_PP_INTERNAL_CAT(_1, _2) _1##_2
      |                                       ^~
/home/gidi/temp/gtest/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h:76:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘GMOCK_PP_VARIADIC_CALL’
   76 |   GMOCK_PP_VARIADIC_CALL(GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_ARG_, __VA_ARGS__)
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Test.h:14:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘MOCK_METHOD’
   14 |   MOCK_METHOD(int, Sum, (int x, int y), (override));
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~
Test.h:15:21: error: ‘testing::internal::Function<bool(int)>::Result MockFoo::ComplexJob(testing::internal::ElemFromList<0, int>::type)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
   15 |   MOCK_METHOD(bool, ComplexJob, (int x), (override));
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/gidi/temp/gtest/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-pp.h:17:31: note: in definition of macro ‘GMOCK_PP_IDENTITY’
   17 | #define GMOCK_PP_IDENTITY(_1) _1
      |                               ^~
/home/gidi/temp/gtest/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h:93:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_IMPL’
   93 |   GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_IMPL(                                            \
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/gidi/temp/gtest/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-pp.h:152:39: note: in expansion of macro ‘GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_ARG_4’
  152 | #define GMOCK_PP_INTERNAL_CAT(_1, _2) _1##_2
      |                                       ^~
/home/gidi/temp/gtest/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h:76:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘GMOCK_PP_VARIADIC_CALL’
   76 |   GMOCK_PP_VARIADIC_CALL(GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_ARG_, __VA_ARGS__)
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Test.h:15:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘MOCK_METHOD’
   15 |   MOCK_METHOD(bool, ComplexJob, (int x), (override));
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~
Test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void FooTest_Test_Test::TestBody()’:
Test.cpp:11:30: error: ‘NewPermanentCallback’ was not declared in this scope
   11 |       .WillRepeatedly(Invoke(NewPermanentCallback(Sum3, 1)));
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:20: Test.o] Error 1
```

Comment: We need more details, what kind of issues ? How do you compile it ? Please give us the compiler errors.

Comment: I found it by searching "‘NewPermanentCallback’ was not declared in this scope" on google. When you have a long stacktrace, try to read the first or the last error, and go from there.

Comment: Thanks @kaios, I managed to use the link you suggested to solve my problem. Had to make some tweaks, but finally I was able to make it work.